# Regular automatic export of Kusto data into better queryable format?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

We have two Kusto / Azure Data Explorer clusters with specific tables that contain data I want to expose through a web API.

At the moment, I'm using `Kusto.Data.Net.Client` (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data/) to retrieve this information from one of the clusters.

Problems:

- The 2nd cluster doesn't allow programmatic access.
- The queries are slow and there's lots of overhead I don't need. Kusto is meant for massive amounts of data, I only need tiny bits.

Possible solution:

Regularly and automatically export portions of Kusto data (based onto a query) into another database (Postgres, Cosmos DB) and let the API work on this.

Questions:

- Is this a recommended approach?
- How would I do this (create that automatic export)? What's the tooling to use?

Comment: What do you mean by _The 2nd cluster doesn't allow programmatic access._?

Comment: I can only query it when logging in with my personal account. No "app user" allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest two options:

1. You can use [continuous export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/continuous-data-export) which would periodically export data from your cluster to storage account.
   You can then create an [event grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-grid-overview) on your second cluster, to read from that storage account into your kusto cluster.
2. Create a [follower cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/follower?tabs=csharp), that would follow only the specific tables you need from the first cluster. This would automatically get the data from the first cluster (aka leader) and querying the follower would not incur any latency on it. More information [here](https://yonileibowitz.github.io/blog-posts/follower-cluster.html)

Comment: I looked at option 2 because it seems to be what I'm looking for. However, this syntax `cluster('leader.westus.kusto.windows.net').database('MyDatabase').table('MyTable')` gives me an error. The lead cluster doesn't allow this kind of access.

Comment: This is the correct syntax:
`cluster('leader.westus.kusto.windows.net').database('MyDatabase').MyTable`
(no need for the 'table("...' )

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you are looking for is [update policy commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/update-policy), which according to the docs:

> The update policy is a table-level policy object that automatically runs a query and then ingests the results when data is ingested into another table.

This is a good approach to reduce the data.